# Select from list of objects by object attribute value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class

I have a list of objects that are pulled in from an API. Here is the snippet of output (as there's about 300 lines):

```
combo =>
ID: 6, Name:Thomas Partey, Club:1, Position: 3, Price: $4.7, Total Pts: 57    
ID: 7, Name:Martin Ødegaard, Club:1, Position: 3, Price: $7.0, Total Pts: 128    
ID: 8, Name:Kieran Tierney, Club:1, Position: 2, Price: $4.6, Total Pts: 23    
ID: 12, Name:Emile Smith Rowe, Club:1, Position: 3, Price: $5.6, Total Pts: 5
```

I would like to only show the combo where Total Pts = 57

So desired output is just:

```
ID: 6, Name:Thomas Partey, Club:1, Position: 3, Price: $4.7, Total Pts: 57
```

I've tried the following:

```
sorted = combo.select{ |item| item[:totalpoints] == 57 }
puts sorted
```

and

```
sorted = combo.select(&:totalpoints) == 57
```

Full code is here if needed:

```
class Player
attr_accessor :id, :firstname, :secondname, :club, :position, :price, :totalpoints, 
:active
def initialize(id, firstname, secondname, club, position, price, totalpoints, active)
@id = id.to_i
@firstname = firstname.to_s
@secondname = secondname.to_s
@club = club.to_s
@position = position.to_i
@price = price / 10.to_f
@totalpoints = totalpoints.to_i
@active = active.to_i
end

def to_s()
 "  ID: " + @id.to_s + ", Name:" + @firstname.to_s + " " + @secondname.to_s + ", Club:" 
 + 
 @club.to_s + ", Position: " + @position.to_s + ", Price: $" + @price.to_s + ", Total Pts: 
 " + @totalpoints.to_s + "    "
end

def self.pull()
require 'net/http'
require 'json'
url = 'https://fantasy.premierleague.com/api/bootstrap-static/'
uri = URI(url)
response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
object = JSON.parse(response)
elements = object["elements"]
elements.map! { |qb|
    if  qb["chance_of_playing_next_round"].to_f > 0
        Player.new(
            qb["id"],                               # ID
            qb["first_name"],                       # First Name
            qb["second_name"],                      # Surname
            qb["team"],                             # Club
            qb["element_type"],                     # Position
            qb["now_cost"],                         # Current Price
            qb["total_points"],                     # Total Points
            qb["chance_of_playing_next_round"])     # Chance Of Playing
    end
   }
  end


  combo = Player.pull().map{|qb| qb}
```

Comment: It appears that your input is a file and you have shown an image of part of it (`"combo =>"` on one line, `"ID: 6, Name:Thomas Partey,..., Total Pts: 57"` on the next line, and so on. Is that correct? If not, is `combo` a variable holding an array of hashes, constructed from the file contents? If so, you could simplify your question a lot by making `combo` the starting point, making no reference to the file from which it came.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the data from your example you'll need to invoke the `totalpoints` method on each element in `combo` and then compare it with what you want;

```
combo.compact.select { |element| element.totalpoints == 57  }
```

The `compact` use is to remove the elements that are nil otherwise you'll get an exception when invoking a method that hasn't been defined on a Nil object (that's the easiest way I could think of, there might be others).

Notice this won't work as expected;

```
combo.select(&:totalpoints) == 57
```

because select will be yielding true for every element with a "truthy" value when the method `totalpoints` is invoked on it. And that result will then be compared to 57 which will never work as intended because the given result might be an array or a hash.